# create vue.js v-model from dynamci value

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am generating a some checkbox dynamically. Now I need to create v-model dynamic.

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
   <label class="form-group-title">DIETARY PREFERENCES</label>
    <p>Please mark appropriate boxes if it applies to you and/or your family</p>
      <div class="check-group" v-for="v in alldietry" :key="v">
           <input type="checkbox" v-model="userinfo.{{#Here will be the value}}" value="" id="Vegetarian"> 
      <label for="Vegetarian">{{v.title}}</label>
        </div>
  </div>
```

into the `v-model` I have try `v-model="userinfo.{{xyz}}"` its shows error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `{{ }}` interpolation inside attributes.

The `v-model` value is a javascript expression, so instead of

```
v-model="userinfo.{{xyz}}"
```

you can just do

```
v-model="userinfo[xyz]"
```

as you would normally do in javascript when accessing a dynamic property of an object.

Answer (score 1):

To bind dynamic object to model, you need to access to key shared by the model value and the set of data used to display your list.

```js
let vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
  data: {
    userinfo: {
      0: '',
      1: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    alldietry() {
      return [
       {
          id: 0,
          title: 'Title'
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Title'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="form-group input-group">
  <label class="form-group-title">DIETARY PREFERENCES</label>
  <p>Please mark appropriate boxes if it applies to you and/or your family</p>
  <div class="check-group" v-for="(v, index) in alldietry" :key="index">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="userinfo[v.id]" value="" :id="v.id"> 
    <label :for="v.id">{{v.title}}</label>
  </div>
  {{ userinfo }}
</div>
```